# How do you get to compare the output of whoami /groups to check whether a certain value is present in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I would like to ask a little bit of assitance with my code, what I am trying to do is check if a certain group SID value is present to the user running the file. I have tried the one below but the `if statement` part doesn't work. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
function IsPartAdmin {
    if ((whoami /groups) -like "S-1-5-32-544") {
        Write-Host "User is part of the admin group"
    }else{
        Write-Host "User is not part of the admin group"
    }

}
```

Comment: Add wildcards to the `-like` pattern `"*S-1-5-32-544*"`

Comment: Try adding the wildcards to match strings before and after the search text `-like "*S-1-5-32-544*"`

Comment: is there a reason to NOT use the local user/group cmdlets? this ... >>> `(Get-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators).Where({$_.Name.Split('\')[-1] -eq $env:USERNAME})` <<< ... seems to let one know if a given user in is the admin group.

Comment: You can also use `-match` which matches any part of a string with regular expressions.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey `Get-LocalGroupMember` would only give you the immediate members of the group - `whoami /groups` shows all SID's in the users token, including those resolved through indirect group memberships

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - ooo! thank you for the info! i learned something today ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

As the legend, Lee Daily, commented.. why whoami vs other options? However, to help answer your specific question, we need to address a couple of things.

First, the output of `whoami /groups` is just a mess of text. If this was our only option, you'd need to do some text parsing, possibly regex matching, etc. Luckily there is a parameter to control the output format. Thus we will change the command to

```
whoami /groups /FO csv
```

Now we can do stuff easily with that output in powershell.

```
whoami /groups /FO csv | convertfrom-csv
```

You'll see well formed objects with properties, one is the SID of the groups. Now we can use one of many operators to find what we are looking for. I chose to use `-contains`

```
function IsPartAdmin {
    if ((whoami /groups /FO csv | convertfrom-csv).sid -contains "S-1-5-32-544") {
        Write-Host "User is part of the admin group"
    }else{
        Write-Host "User is not part of the admin group"
    }
}
```

`-eq` and `-match` would work the same as `-contains` in the previous example. You could also flip it like this with `-in`

```
function IsPartAdmin {
    if ("S-1-5-32-544" -in (whoami /groups /FO csv | convertfrom-csv).sid) {
        Write-Host "User is part of the admin group"
    }else{
        Write-Host "User is not part of the admin group"
    }
}
```